# pycharm remote interpreter with two factor authentication

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I would like to use PyCharm with a remote interpreter (in fact using the remote directory structure). The server I am connecting to has two factor authentication which requires a password and time changing code.

1. How do I setup a login so that PyCharm prompts me for the one time use code?
2. Will PyCharm use the remote directory structure as I would like or will it keep saving things locally?